# LIKE search in punycode values in postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2, idn, punycode

When storing a domain in punycode, postgresql loses the ability to match the LIKE operator by the original, non-encoded value. For example, if we encode smth like `примерен.site` (example in Bulgarian), we get xn--e1aahqhhhd.site in our database.
It would seem that translating part of the search word into punycode before querying the database should solve the problem, but the translation of part of the source string (`примерен.site`) does not match the corresponding part of the encoded one.
For example, примере = xn--e1aahqngd, not xn--e1aahqhhh. Accordingly, `примере`, translated in punycode will not return proper result when requesting:
`SELECT * FROM domains where domains.domain LIKE '%xn--e1aahqngd%';`

I've tried various postgresql built-in functions like envelope or decode, but they don't support punycode.
Something like
`SELECT * FROM domains where domains.domain LIKE '% (punycode(примере) ) %';`
would be perfect, but I couldn't find it.

The simple answer is to create another column (or table in postgresql) where the original unencoded domain name ​​will be stored and LIKE search will be possible on them, but I hope that I am not the first to encounter this or a similar problem and there will be people who will share their experience of solving)

P.S.: My api is written in Yii2, maybe there is a tool in it there that could help.

Comment: There is no solution to this, other than to store the original and search within that. Punycode is not an encoding that could be performed on only "parts" of the value, and expected to get the same output. The punycode for `äö` is different than the punycodes for `ä` and `ö` combined.

Comment: As Cbroe says, this can't be solved. The problem isn't new, for example people who store (partly) base64-encoded text in a column have had the same problem for decades already.

Comment: Ok, thanks for feedback everybody, at least I will not waste time on further search in wrong direction